# How do I get status, logs of last run `state.highstate` in Salt?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I applied state using:

```
$sudo salt 'api-*' state.highstate -l debug -v
```

Some states failed and I scrolled down, fixed some and now I can't scroll up (my terminal doesn't save full session) to see the stdout.

Now I don't want to run high state again. I checked `jobs.lookup_jid`, but it doesn't display anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the log files at `/var/log/salt/minion`

Comment: I cannot check logs of particular minion. Otherwise I have start with each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`jobs.lookup_jid` gives you the return data from that job. If you don't know the job ID, you can list recently-run jobs using `salt-run jobs.list_jobs`:

```
# salt-run jobs.list_jobs
20150924134212132446:
    ----------
    Arguments:
    Function:
        test.ping
    StartTime:
        2015, Sep 24 13:42:12.132446
    Target:
        saltmine
    Target-type:
        glob
    User:
        root
```

It's not clear which logs you want. If you want logs from the minion, you can try tailing the minion log using `salt <minion_id> cmd.run 'tail -n100 /var/log/salt/minion`.

Comment: hi, the `lookup_jid` does not include failures etc or can you tell me exact command?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the job id from `jobs.list_jobs`

```
$> salt-run jobs.list_jobs --out=json
{
    "20190308173940124336": {
        "Function": "state.apply", 
        "Target": "dev-baqar-service-0", 
        "User": "ubuntu", 
        "StartTime": "2019, Mar 08 17:39:40.124336", 
        "Target-type": "glob", 
        "Arguments": []
    }
}
```

and then run the following to get the highstate output:

```
salt-run jobs.lookup_jid 20190308173940124336 --out=highstate
```